# difference between account ssh-key vs deployment ssh-key

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Can someone please explain what is the difference between account ssh-key vs deployment ssh-key?

I have made use of them frequently but never tried to learn how they differ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your **ssh account key** does **identify you**, and allows you to interact with GitHub as you (meaning for instance; you can push to your own repo)

Your ssh deploy key, as mentioned in "[Read-only deploy keys](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys)" are keys with read-only access.
**It does not authenticate you**.

> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on your server and grants access to a single GitHub repository. **They are often used to clone repositories during deploys or continuous integration runs**.
>   Deploys sometimes involve merging branches and pushing code, so deploy keys have always allowed both read and write access. Because write access is undesirable in many cases, **you now have the ability to create deploy keys with read-only access**.

You can create a read/write deploy key, but its ability to be read-only is in contrast with an account SSH key: the latter (SSH key) will *always* be for read/write access to your repositories.

You find the same purpose for [deploy keys at BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-deployment-keys-294486051.html):

> A deployment key grants read-only access to a public or private repository. With a deployment key a user or a process can pull or clone a repository over SSH. Deployment keys have the following features and limitations:
>
> - Deployment keys do not apply to your plan limit.
> - You can add the same deployment key to multiple repositories.
> - The deployment key must be unique — it cannot also be associated with an account.

Comment: So basically, you use the same SSH key, in "BitBucket settings" for authentication and in your "repository settings" for read-only use. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: No it would be a separate SSH key, registered on Bitbucket as a deployment key.

Comment: @VonC is this answer in need of an update? My understanding of deploy keys is that they can allow write access (there's a checkbox when creating one)

Comment: @user5783745 The link I mention does include "so deploy keys have always allowed both read and write access". I never said the contrary. I just emphasizes that they can be read only (as opposed to an account ssh key, which always give read/write access)

Comment: If I have a ssh key, I do not need a deploy repo key? What if I use a CI tool like Travis? Do I need a deploy repo key then?

Comment: @Timo A deploy key is more a technical way for a CI to access your repo. Your SSH key is a way to authenticate you. If you need to push, use your key. If you have a CI which just needs to access your repo, use a deploy key.