# Added a deploy key to a private repo within an organization, but still can't clone the repo

Tags: git, ssh

On a linux server, I've successfully added an ssh key using `ssh-keygen`, added it to the list of keys available within `ssh-agent` by using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_new_private_key`, and then I've added that public key into the deploy keys section within my organization's private repo. That deploy key also has write access.

However, when I go to run `git clone` using the SSH link, it gives me the following error:

```
# git clone git@github.myorg/myprivaterepo.git
Cloning into 'myprivaterepo'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing? I have followed the guide here https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys to successfully add the deploy key, but no luck with trying to clone.

Comment: do you have ~/.ssh/config file, if yes, please paste

Comment: You are using git hub or bitbucket?

Comment: No `/.ssh/config` file and yes I'm using GitHub.

Comment: ok, you need to add the keys in Github --> Settings --> SSH and GPG --> Add ssh key

Comment: This would have to be added as my personal account right? Can I not add an SSH key specifically for a github repo on an organization account?

Comment: I've done that and it still doesn't work. Makes no sense. I have my public SSH key added to my personal Github profile, which is the owner of the organization and an admin of the repo, but still can't git clone via ssh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659302/difference-between-account-ssh-key-vs-deployment-ssh-key

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- `ssh -Tv git@github.myorg` work, meaning it displays a welcome message
- you are using a proper SSH URL, like `git@github.myorg:<me>/myprivaterepo.git`: note the '`:` after `git@github.myorg`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution, you can create `fine grained access token` for the specific repos that you need.
Here is a link explaining creation of access token 
 https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

You can see in the image below, I created fine grained access token for my private repo findFalcone.
N.B.: You have to carefully select what all permissions that token will have, I just added one permission primarily to allow read and write access to repo.
After you have the token you can use this format to clone the private repo 
`git clone https://<username>:<personal_access_token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 step process to use deploy keys properly
Step 1: create ssh key using following command
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your github email"`

Step 2: assuming `/root/.ssh/find` is the path to your private file and `akshayjai1` is your username, you have to add following snippet into your .ssh/config file

```
Host github.com:akshayjai1
        Hostname github.com
        IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/find
```

Step 3: add private key to your linux VM using command `ssh-add /root/.ssh/find`

Step 4: put the public key in the deploy keys section of concerned repository. Note it is mentioned on docs, that you have to create separate pair of deploy keys for each repository.

Hope it helps!